# Cronjob doesn't execute (Cygwin)

Tags: cron, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin to synchronize folders between a Windows-Machine and an Apache server. It works fine if I execute the commands, but I can't get Cronjob to work properly.

I tried to create a simple mkdir command as a cronjob and when I save the crontab, it successfully installs it.

My Cronjob is:
`*/1 * * * * mkdir newfolder`

I wait for the new folder to pup up, but nothing happens.

In the `cron.log` it says:

`Cron 7072 fork: child -1 - CREATEPROCESSW failed for c:cygwin/usr/sbin/cron.exe, errno 30`

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem: (drumroll)
I reconfigurated it... often!

I kept trying "cron-config" time after time and now it works. I'm still not any smarter what I configurated wrong/right.

I'm sorry for the vague help if anybody with the same problem stumbles upon this.